# Is it possible to use git hub login for local sonar application?

Tags: github, jenkins, oauth, sonarqube

Is it possible to use git hub login for sonar application?
Just like Jenkins can be configured.
if possible please provide steps to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [SonarQube GitHub Authentication Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Authentication+Plugin) has been created since the accepted answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

For SONAR you need not connect with GITHUB directly, use jenkins to get the latest code to your agent and in the smae job invoke your sonar analysis - either using runner or maven goals, it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no plugin allowing the delegation of authentication to GitHub